# Unhandled exception when open nuget.exe

Tags: .net, nuget, build-server

when i opening the nuget command line tool i get the following exception but i dont know why.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxH1e.png)

```
C:\tools>nuget.exe

Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.NotSupportedException: Das angeforderte Sicherheit
sprotokoll wird nicht unterstützt.
   bei System.Net.ServicePointManager.set_SecurityProtocol(SecurityProtocolType
value)
   bei NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args
)
   bei NuGet.CommandLine.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I dont have install any Visual Studio Version because i try to create a .NET build Server without visual Studio. I have try install another .NET Framework but the unhandled exception remains when i open the nuget.exe.

Can you help me?

Comment: Could you please translate error text to English?

Comment: Google "nuget configure tls protocol" for basic hits.  You always need to document the version number when you ask a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

> Das angeforderte Sicherheitsprotokoll wird nicht unterstützt.

The required security protocol is not supported. That means your combination of Windows installation and .NET framework does not support whatever Nuget deems to be their security protocol of choice (TLS 1.2 as far as I remember).

Use a recent/supported windows installation, be up-to-date on security fixes and install a .NET Framework with all security fixes.